# Why is momentJS giving me a negative start_epoch time here?

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

```
moment(this.endEpoch).subtract(3, 'month').unix()
```

`this.endEpoch` is today's date or by the time of this posting: `1484670569`

This should produce a start_epoch date that is just 3 months ago, however it creates a negative number :( `-6467730`

Any idea what is going wrong here?

[**Moment Docs on substract**](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/)

> moment().subtract('seconds', 1); // Deprecated in 2.8.0
>
> moment().subtract(1, 'seconds');

I tried both versions and they produce the same negative start_epoch number.

Comment: multiply `this.endEpoch` by 1000, because moment accept a timestamp with milliseconds, while you pass it a value in seconds

Comment: shouldn't it be `months` (plural) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass a timestamp that contains value in seconds but moment needs a milliseconds too, so this code should work right:

```
moment(this.endEpoch * 1000).subtract(3, 'month').unix()
```

or use `unix()` method on it:

```
moment.unix(this.endEpoch).subtract(3, 'month').unix()
```

Comment: Ah thanks! Good to know :D yeah the moment.unix solves the conversion of string to number and the milisecs problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `moment.unix(this.endEpoch)` when using a unix timestamp in seconds.

Source: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`moment.unix`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/) instead of [`moment(Number)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/)

```js
var endEpoch = 1484670569;
console.log(moment(endEpoch).format());
console.log(moment.unix(endEpoch).format());
var res = moment.unix(endEpoch).subtract(3, 'month').unix()
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```